# How to detect if a device get my phone bluetooth name?

Tags: android, bluetooth, pic

I'm using a bluetooth modul (HC-05) to detect if an android phone is in the modul's range.
I tried to connect with HC-05 (as master) and a PIC16f887 to the phone, but I can't. Searched many pages on net how to use HC-05 as master, but no solution.
So, finally I could do this by modul get my phone's BT name. If it could, my phone is in range.
But now I want my phone to detect this "remote name query" and play some sound then.
Sorry for my poor english :)

Answer (score 2):

Im guessing you want something like this: [VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=23&v=iOKnygzagcg)

**Lets start with the basics:**

The typical default factory settings for a new Bluetooth HC-05 module are:

- Default Bluetooth Name: “HC-05”
- Default Password: 1234 or 0000
- Default Communication: Slave Device
- Default Mode: Data Mode
- Default Data Mode Baud Rate: 9600, 8, N, 1
- Default Command Mode Baud Rate: 38400, 8, N, 1
- Default firmware: LINVOR

---

**1. To TEST Bluetooth connections from your android device use id suggest you use this** [**APK**](https://howtomechatronics.com/download/arduino-bluetooth-tutorial-example-android-app/?wpdmdl=2833&ind=0)

**2. Connect the HC-05 BT module as shown in the diagram**

[image]

**3. Initialize the UART receiver at the microcontroller end (side)**

(code includes 2 leds for pin 33 and pin 34)

```
/*
* LAB Number: 17
* LAB Name: Bluetooth Module HC-05 Interfacing (Smartphone -> MCU)
* Author: Khaled Magdy
* For More Information Visit My Website @ DeepBlueMbedded.com
*
*/

#include <xc.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "config.h"
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
//--[ Control Data ]--
#define Blue_LED_ON    49
#define Blue_LED_OFF   50
#define Yellow_Toggle  51
//--------------------------------
// Functions Declarations
void UART_RX_Init(void);
// Globals
uint8_t UART_Buffer = 0;
//--------------------------------

// Main Routine
void main(void)
{
  //--[ Peripherals & IO Configurations ]--
  UART_RX_Init(); // Initialize The UART in Master Mode @ 9600bps
  TRISB0 = 0;     // Blue LED  (Switch)
  TRISB1 = 0;     // Yellow LED (Toggle)
  RB0 = 0;        // Initially OFF
  RB1 = 0;        // Initially OFF
  //---------------------------
  while(1) 
  {

  }
  return;
}
//--------------------------------
// Functions Definitions

void UART_RX_Init()
{
  BRGH = 1; // Set For High-Speed Baud Rate
  SPBRG = 25; // Set The Baud Rate To Be 9600 bps
  // Enable The Ascynchronous Serial Port
  SYNC = 0;
  SPEN = 1;
  // Set The RX-TX Pins to be in UART mode (not io)
  TRISC6 = 1; // As stated in the datasheet
  TRISC7 = 1; // As stated in the datasheet
  //--[ Enable UART Receiving Interrupts ]--
  RCIE = 1; // UART Receving Interrupt Enable Bit
  PEIE = 1; // Peripherals Interrupt Enable Bit
  GIE = 1; // Global Interrupt Enable Bit
  //------------------
  CREN = 1; // Enable Data Continous Reception
}

void interrupt ISR (void)
{
  if (RCIF == 1)
  {
    UART_Buffer = RCREG; // Read The Received Data Buffer

    // This could have been done within the main loop. Since it's not
    // Excessive processing, so it's OK to do it here below
    if(UART_Buffer == Blue_LED_ON)
      RB0 = 1; // Blue LED ON
    if(UART_Buffer == Blue_LED_OFF)
      RB0 = 0; // Blue LED OFF
    if(UART_Buffer == Yellow_Toggle)
      RB1 = ~RB1; // Toggle Yellow LED 

    RCIF = 0; // Clear The Interrupt Flag
  }
}
```

**NOTE** The Data Bytes (49, 50, and 51) are the ASCII equivalents for the numeric characters (1, 2, and 3 respectively).

**4. Download this apk to send commands to your HC05:** [APK](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.NAL.bluetoothcontroller&gl=IE)

**For more info follow Reference:** [LINK](https://deepbluembedded.com/bluetooth-module-hc05-interfacing-pic-microcontroller-tutorial/)

Comment: Check this out: [LINK](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/22484/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-device-connected-to-the-bluetooth#comment42739_22484)